# Can we use spring prototype bean together with try-with-resources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

Want to know if we can use spring prototype bean with try-with-resources mechanism:

`MyResource` implements `AutoCloseable`

Suppose I have a bean defined as:

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceCreation {

    @Bean()
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MyResource createResource() {
        return new MyResource("Test");
    }
}
```

I have a factory class to generate the prototype beans:

```
public class ResourceFactory() {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext m_applicationContext;

    public static generateResource() {
        return m_applicationContext.getBean(MyResource.Class);
    }
}
```

Then to use try-with-resources:

```
try (MyResource = ResourceFactory.generateResource()) {
    ...
}
```

So in this way, is there any problem? Because spring container should manage the lifecycle of the prototype bean.
Will the `close()` method in the `MyResource` gets called after the try block ends?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: Yes thanks to try-with-resources.

**Long answer**:

These two are completely unrelated concepts. You are mixing *try-with-resources*(1) which is a java concept and the *destroyMethod*(2), a callback method of a spring managed bean.

Explaining per point:

1. **try-with-resources**: it's a syntactic sugar (Java 1.7 or later) for:

```
    MyResource  myResource = ResourceFactory.generateResource();

    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        myResource.close();
    }
```

and it will be called for any class that implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable` or `java.io.Closeable` interface.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html

2. **destroyMethod** it's a callback method, that spring lets you implement, called before the instance is destroyed by the container as per: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-nature

But,

In case of a prototype bean, Spring does not manage his complete  lifecycle; initialization lifecycle callback methods are called on all objects regardless of scope, in the case of prototypes, configured destruction lifecycle callbacks are not called.

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype